# How to git push in the openshift without retarting the gears?

Tags: openshift

Every time I make a git push. All the cartridges in the openshift gears will restart. it takes really long time. Can I make git push without restarting the gears ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realize it by enabling the [Hot Deployment](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/modifying-applications.html)

**Windows**

Enable hot deployment by creating the hot_deploy marker file in the application’s root directory with the following command:

```
C:\app_directory> copy NUL > .openshift\markers\hot_deploy
```

Disable hot deployment by deleting the hot_deploy marker file.

**Mac OS X and Linux**

Enable hot deployment by creating the hot_deploy marker file in the application’s root directory:

```
$ touch .openshift/markers/hot_deploy
```

Disable hot deployment by deleting the hot_deploy marker file.

Comment: This is great, but even with hot-deploy enabled the server is still inaccessible briefly (in my case 10 seconds of downtime). Is there any way to make git push only copy the files and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

When you want Openshift to redeploy your application without restarting the gears - you can use the `hot_deploy` marker (see the above answer). However, not every cartridge type supports the hot deploy.

BUT

when you don't want Openshift to deploy the app nor to restart your app's gears, you can disable the auto-deployment feature. See https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/deployments.html#enabling-disabling-automatic-deployment.

```
rhc app-configure YOURAPP --no-auto-deploy
```

You will be able to deploy your app manually when you are ready to do so, using the `rhc deploy` command.